# Error with sm.density.compare error

Tags: r

I am an r novice and currently analyzing my data, so forgive me if my error is basic.
I am trying to use sm.density.compare function in the sm package to compare the abundance and diversity of parasite across host species and region.
The data I am trying to analyze is similar to the iris dataset. The iris data is working but when I try to run my data, I get the error "Error in x * w : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
Here is my code:

```
sm.density.compare(Data_Sheets_FINAL$Total.Endos, Data_Sheets_FINAL$Species)
```

The species data is broken into three groups (AS, CS, and TSE). Here is my Total.Endos data:

```
[1]  221   46  413  477   29  294  196  298  592  331   20  339   36  123  119  158   34  258  264  160  224  184  452
[24]  103   17  133  128  311   13   98  387  152   74 1058   13  110   66    9   17    5   22  530  146   73   44  277
[47]   75   27   68   49  115   67  104  108  256  762   93   21 1604   47   13   79  213   32   15   10   38  369  108
[70]  270   70  432  246   14   72   12   34   79  167
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message that you get if your Species are strings. Try

```
Data_Sheets_FINAL$Species = factor(Data_Sheets_FINAL$Species)
sm.density.compare(Data_Sheets_FINAL$Total.Endos, Data_Sheets_FINAL$Species)
```